# Why is it failing to connect to my Azure SQL Server Database?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server

I have an azure sql server named "myCloudServer" and I created 2 databases in it, DB1 and DB2. I am an admin so I used the server admin "pt_admin" to create and manage those 2 databases. I wanted to give a 'read-access' to another person where he can login and do all kind of "Select" queries.

I connected to the master database and executed the following commands:

```
CREATE LOGIN readonlylogin WITH password='1231!#ASDF!a';

CREATE USER readonlyuser FROM LOGIN readonlylogin;
```

Then I went into DB1 and DB2 and executed the following commands for each database:

```
CREATE USER readonlyuser FROM LOGIN readonlylogin;

EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_datareader', 'readonlyuser';
```

All the commands were successfully executed by "pt_admin" user. Afterward, I tried to connect (SQL Auth) using the following credentials:

```
username: readonlyuser 
password: 1231!#ASDF!a
```

and it is failing for some reason with a message

```
cannot connect to "myCloudServer" and that the login failed for user "readonlyuser". Error Code 18456
```

**Note that I made sure I had my IP_Address added to the firewall in azure.**

Any idea how to debug or fix this issue?

Comment: Did you run through the troubleshooter? In your case, error 18456, fourth option here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/10085/troubleshooting-connectivity-issues-with-microsoft-azure-sql-database

Comment: You should be using the login name to connect to the server. UserName is relevant at the database level.

Comment: You're right! it was a stupid mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Error Code 18456

Error code 18456 means that login failed for user

As Amit Sukralia mentioned that in your case **readonlyuser** is related to database level, you can't use that to connect the server.

You could use the **readonlylogin** to connect the server.

You also could use [SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-2017) to check that.

[image]

Comment: Totally mixed that login with the username .. Thanks!